VS Code The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: -1073741819
When I try to run code in VS Code, it shows this error immediately. It was running code fine the other day and started crashing out of nowhere. Powershell also closes when I try to open it outside of vs.
I tried sfc /scannow. I also tried disabling the PowerShell feature, restarting, enabling, and restarting.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/vs-code-the-terminal-process/cb5decad-9acc-4bc4-9153-c94a6f1ec8ed

What is the output from these four (4) commands? Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -Property Caption,Version,
(Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('DisplayVersion'),
code --version,
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()

I couldn't run the first, second, or fourth in CMD as administrator, but code --version is: 1.88.1 e170252f762678dec6ca2cc69aba1570769a5d39 x64 Powershell immediately exits with code 3221225477 (0x0000005)
